# Row reduce of a matrix mod 2

Tags: python-2.7, matrix

So I have two matrices, `E` and `I` I stack them together horizontally and perform a different kind of row reduce than the one we know (Echelon). In this row reduce, starting with the first column on the left-hand side, we find the first row with a 1 in that column and add it modulo 2 (0 + 0 = 1 + 1 =0, 0 + 1 = 1 + 0 = 1) to each of the succeeding rows with a 1 in that
column. We then eliminate this first row with a 1 in the first column. The procedure is repeated by finding the first row with a 1 in the
second column, adding it to each succeeding row with a 1 in the second
column and then eliminating the first row with a 1 in the second column.
This is continued until we obtain a row in which the columns of `E`
are all 0's.

```
import numpy 
E = numpy.random.random_integers(0, 100, (5, 3))
I = numpy.eye(5)

EstackI = numpy.hstack((E,I))
EstackI = EstackI%2

matrix = EstackI

def addRowsMod2(first, second):
    return [((x + y) % 2) for x, y in zip(first, second)]

numColsE = E.shape[1]  # the number of columns in E

def rowReduceStep(col, matrix):
    selectedRow = -1
    numRows = len(matrix)
    for rowIndex in range(numRows):
        row = list(matrix[rowIndex])
        if row[col] == 1:
            selectedRow = rowIndex
            break

    if selectedRow != -1:
        for i in range(selectedRow + 1, numRows):
            if matrix[i][col] == 1:
                matrix[i] = addRowsMod2(matrix[i], matrix[selectedRow])

    newMatrix = []
    for i in range(numRows):
        if i != selectedRow:
            newMatrix += [matrix[i]]
    return (newMatrix, selectedRow)

for col in range(numColsE):
    result = rowReduceStep(col, matrix)
    matrix = result[0]

finalMat = matrix
```

Above is my code, I do end up with an output with 0's in `E` and a combination of 0's and 1's in `I`. However, I know this isn't the right result (this is just a part of my huge project, I go on to use the locations of 1's in `I` later and the matrix size is actually much larger (63 x 90) my text has a printout for 2 lines of this large matrix and that is how I know this isn't working right. Any help will be appreciated. )

Comment: You need to learn simple debugging techniques. Construct a small example where you can compute the result by hand and the code produces the wrong answer. Then print or use a debugger to examine intermediate results of the computation to see where they diverge from your hand calculation. It's not that hard. Then add this test case to your unit test suite.

Comment: Thanks @Gene will try debugging it